# How do PERMISSIONS get changed on Macbook and how does one change them back?

Tags: macbook-pro, permission, catalina

I keep getting this message

"The document “NDA 2019 CONFIDENTIALITY” could not be saved as “NDA 2019 CONFIDENTIALITY.pages”. You don’t have permission. To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info."

I personally use this MacBook pro 99.99% of the time and I never changed any permissions nor had issues like this before. I am not getting messages telling me I cannot save changed docs because I don't have permission. I went through steps to reset all permissions, then rebooted...but still same issue.

Any thoughts?

[image: Here is the GET INFO for the file]

When I try to change that to READ & WRITE it won't let me.

Here are the command and answer when entered into Terminal:

SizzleBook-Pro:~ sizzle$ ls -dlOe@ /Volumes/GoogleDrive/My\ Drive/RODENHISER 
drwx------  2 sizzle  staff  - 4096 Sep  4 13:20 /Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/RODENHISER

Comment: What kind of access rights does the folder have into which you put the file?

Comment: @nohillside I believe it has READ & WRITE permissions. I haven't changed anything myself and have been using it the same way for a year +. When I see privileges I change them all to READ & WRITE.

Comment: Please add screenshots of the "Get Info" dialog boxes. Also, can you open Terminal, type `ls -dlOe@ ` (that's the letter O) followed by a space, drag/drop the folder into Terminal and press Enter? And then copy/paste both the command and the output you got into your question.

Comment: @nohillside I have done so above

Comment: How did you mount google drive

Comment: @Mark Good question...I believe I need to remount it because I have been having some issues with that. I suppose I need to remount it but I am not sure how. I have Drive on the Finder sidebar but if I try to click it from there I get "“Google Drive” can’t be opened because the original item can’t be found. Thoughts? Help?

Comment: I think you need to run  the google drive app and set that up - I am surprised it is under /Volumes - if so do you have a plain personal Google drive or a more complex business one

Comment: @Mark I have a GSuite Drive account but only one user. I have an appointment with Google Support tomorrow to see if we can fix it.